# An algorithm or a library to give structure to OCR-ed tabular data

Tags: algorithm, ocr

I'm using OCR to read poorly legible sheets of tabulated data. The data coming from OCR contain a lot of typos and incorrectly extracted items. There is a definition of the correct data structure that should be extracted from the tables. My task is to find a procedure to clean the data coming from OCR and extract as many useful datapoints as possible. For example:

In the data I expect following datapoints:

> height - decimal value in range 0.01 to 10.0 expressed in meters
>
> width - decimal value in range 0.01 to 10.0 expressed in meters
>
> weight - integer value in range 5 to 50 expressed in kilograms
>
> colour - string with values "red", "yellow", or "orange"
>
> ... etc.

From OCR I get:

> neiont: l2.G n
>
> weion: 14 ko
>
> oolowr: veHou

Given the aforementioned constraints I should be able to resolve the OCR output to:

> height: 12.5 m
>
> weight: 14 kg
>
> colour: yellow

Can you suggest a general algorithm, technique or optimization procedure or perhaps even a ready-made library that could be employed to handle this task?

Comment: Is all the input written by the same person (or a small number of identifiabe people)?

Comment: The input is printed using a small set of common fonts, but the images are often deformed because they were taken by camera on a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

That's a tall order! Might be beyond the scope of SO. More in the lines of a patentable invention.

There's a whole lot of things that need to be taken into account. For one thing, how can you know the G should be a 5 versus an unclosed 6? Yeah, your eye can tell, but teaching the computer that IS what OCR is.

Not to mention poorly written 7's being interpreted as "I".

At least the colors only have 3 possible values...

Comment: I'm probably gonna get down voted for that, but the truth can be brutal sometimes)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, anyway. I do not count on finding a perfect solution. I'm just looking for ideas that might help me to increase the proportion of useful data that I'm able to extract.